# Maximum likelihood estimation problem

Tags: probability, statistics, maximum-likelihood

> In a town, there are taxis labeled from $1$ to $n$ ($n$ is the total number of taxis). We arrive in the town and see a taxi with label $100$. With the method of maximum likelihood estimation, find $n$.

The solution says $n=100$, but I can't figure out why.

Comment: While the MLE estimates $n$ to be $100$, following the German Tank Problem, the estimate will be $2\cdot 100 - 1=199$

Answer (score 2):

The likelihood on this data is $1/n$ if $n\ge 100$ and zero otherwise (since a draw of $100$ is impossible if $n<100$). This is maximized for $n=100,$ so the MLE is $100.$

Comment: I would like to ask when do you use then 1/n=L(n) and since we have only one sample it means ln(1/n)=ln(L(n)) and 1/n=0 with derivation but I know it doesent make sense. So I want to know when to use logarithm and derivations

Comment: Clearly $n$ must be at least 100. To maximize the likelihood then $1/n$ needs to be as large as possible, i.e. n as small as possible. Thus $n$ must be 100.

Comment: @MirjanPecenko : Taking logarithms in MLE problems is very useful in many instances, but not this one, and you shouldn't apply it without thinking. Moreover, setting derivatives to $0$ to find maximum points is also very useful in many problems, but not in this one, and again you shouldn't apply it without thinking.

Comment: So I can apply it only when it isn't obvious what the maximum

Comment: @MirjanPecenko Applying the logarithm doesn't do anything substantial. If something maximizes $f(\theta)$ it maximizes $\log(f(\theta))$ and vice versa, and it's usually easier to work with the log since it's a sum rather than a product. But the lesson here is that maximization sometimes requires more thought than just taking a derivative. Remember from calculus: the maximum of a differentiable function can occur at a critical pt *or at one of the endpoints of the interval*. This situation is more like when it's at an endpoint (the fact that it's integer-valued complicates things as well).

Comment: In general, if one would observe more taxis, would n be equal to the greatest taxi number?

Answer (score 0):

The probability that the number of the first taxi observed is $100$ is
$$
\begin{cases}
1/n & \text{if there are $n$ taxis and $n\ge100$}, \\
0 & \text{if there are $n$ taxis and } n<100.  
\end{cases}
$$
So the probability is highest when $n=100,$ so that is the maximum-likelihood estimate.